# replace a column of a df with the another column of an another df based on specific condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe as shown below df1 and df2 as shown below.

df1:

```
Date                t_factor     category
2020-02-01             5         A   
2020-02-02             2         B       
2020-02-03             1         C       
2020-02-04             2         A
2020-02-05             3         B
2020-02-06             3         C 
2020-02-07             3         A    
2020-02-08             9         B     
2020-02-09             1         C
2020-02-10             8         A
2020-02-11             3         B         
2020-02-12             3         C
```

df2:

```
Date                  beta     
2020-02-01             100             
2020-02-02             230              
2020-02-03             150           
2020-02-04             100
2020-02-05             200  
2020-02-06             180          
2020-02-07             190            
2020-02-08             290
```

from the above I would like to replace t_factor column of df1 with beta column of df2 based on the input date range.

The function could be like this.

```
def replace_column(df1, df2, start_date = `2020-02-03`, end_date = `2020-02-06`):
     df1 = df1.copy()
     df2 = df2.copy()
     df1 = df1.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=True)
     df2 = df2.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=True)
     df1['t_factor'] = df1['beta']  # for that date range
     return df1
```

**Expected output**: for start_date = `2020-02-03` and  end_date = `2020-02-06`

```
df1:

 Date                t_factor   category
2020-02-01             5         A   
2020-02-02             2         B       
2020-02-03             150       C       
2020-02-04             100       A
2020-02-05             200       B
2020-02-06             180       C 
2020-02-07             3         A    
2020-02-08             9         B     
2020-02-09             1         C
2020-02-10             8         A
2020-02-11             3         B         
2020-02-12             3         C
```

Note: df2 has less data, final date of df2 is `2020-02-08`.

```
if start_date = `2020-02-07`  and end_date = `2020-02-11`.
```

Then **Expected output**:

```
Date                t_factor     category
2020-02-01             5         A   
2020-02-02             2         B       
2020-02-03             1         C       
2020-02-04             2         A
2020-02-05             3         B
2020-02-06             3         C 
2020-02-07             190       A    
2020-02-08             290       B     
2020-02-09             1         C
2020-02-10             8         A
2020-02-11             3         B         
2020-02-12             3         C   

print ('df2 dont have data after 2020-02-08')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `Date` like columns to pandas `datetime` series.

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
```

Then use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and specify the start date(`left`) and end date(`right`)  to create a boolean mask `m`, then use `boolean indexing` with this mask and use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `beta` values from `df2` to `t_function` values in `df1`.

```
m = df1['Date'].between('2020-02-03', '2020-02-06', inclusive=True)
df1.loc[m, 't_factor'] = df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['beta']).fillna(df1['t_factor'])
```

**Another idea** using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
m = df1['Date'].between('2020-02-03', '2020-02-06', inclusive=True)
df1.loc[m, 't_factor'] = df1.pop('beta').fillna(df1['t_factor'])
```

Result:

```
# start=2020-02-03, end=2020-02-06
         Date  t_factor category
0  2020-02-01       5.0        A
1  2020-02-02       2.0        B
2  2020-02-03     150.0        C
3  2020-02-04     100.0        A
4  2020-02-05     200.0        B
5  2020-02-06     180.0        C
6  2020-02-07       3.0        A
7  2020-02-08       9.0        B
8  2020-02-09       1.0        C
9  2020-02-10       8.0        A
10 2020-02-11       3.0        B
11 2020-02-12       3.0        C

# start=2020-02-07, end=2020-02-11.
         Date  t_factor category
0  2020-02-01       5.0        A
1  2020-02-02       2.0        B
2  2020-02-03       1.0        C
3  2020-02-04       2.0        A
4  2020-02-05       3.0        B
5  2020-02-06       3.0        C
6  2020-02-07     190.0        A
7  2020-02-08     290.0        B
8  2020-02-09       1.0        C
9  2020-02-10       8.0        A
10 2020-02-11       3.0        B
11 2020-02-12       3.0        C
```

---

**Function** that wraps the `merging` method `(Method 2)`:

```
def fx(df1, df2, start, end):
    if df2['Date'].max() < pd.Timestamp(end):
        print(f"we dont have data beyound {df2['Date'].max()}")

    df1 =  df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
    m = df1['Date'].between(start, end, inclusive=True)
    df1.loc[m, 't_factor'] = df1.pop('beta').fillna(df1['t_factor'])
    return df1
```

Comment: what if df2 does not have data beyond end_date

Comment: @Danish the code will take care of that condition.. give a min i will add example.

Comment: can you please make it as a function which return df1

Comment: if end_date is more than df2 max date pls print a note that we dont have data in df2 beyond df2.Date.max()

Comment: @Danish which method do you like first or second so that i can make function from it?

Comment: I like second method. Both methods are great.. You are genius. Thank you so much. May god bless you

Comment: what if df1 has more column t_factor, I want all other column as it is. This code will work?

Comment: What do you mean by more column `t_factor`? Can you explain?

Comment: if df1 has more columns than t_factor, sorry for the typo

Comment: yes, @Danish it will work, no problem if having more columns ..

Comment: Thanks.. updated the question by adding one column in df1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217944/discussion-between-danish-and-shubham-sharma).

Comment: pls look into this if you have time.. No one answered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941675/sort-the-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-date-column-of-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses `df.join` and `df.loc` methods.

First initialize the data.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06', '2020-02-12'],'t_factor' : [5, 3, 3, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2020-02-05', '2020-02-06'],'beta' : [200, 180]})
```

Then set `Date` as index.

```
df1d = df1.set_index('Date')
df2d = df2.set_index('Date')
```

Now the key steps.

```
dfres=df1d.join(df2d)
dfres.loc[dfres['beta'].notnull(), 't_factor'] = dfres.loc[dfres['beta'].notnull()].beta
```

One more step to match the expected output.

```
output=dfres.drop(columns='beta')
```

Comment: @Dharman can you pls make a function with parameter df1, df2, start_date, end_date