# Sort the list of dictionaries based on date column of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a  input list and dataframe  as shown below.

```
[{"type": "linear",
  "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
  "days":3,
  "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
  },
 {"type": "quadratic",
  "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z",
  "days":3,
  "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
  },
 {"type": "polynomial",
  "from": "2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
  "days":3,
  "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
  }]
```

df:

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-02             23              
2020-02-03             14           
2020-02-04             23
2020-02-05             23  
2020-02-06             23          
2020-02-07             30            
2020-02-08             29            
2020-02-09             100
2020-03-10             38
2020-03-11             38               
2020-03-12             38                    
2020-03-13             70           
2020-03-14             70
```

Step1: Sort the list based on the value of "from" key in dictionary

```
[
 {"type": "quadratic",
      "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
{"type": "linear",
      "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
     {"type": "polynomial",
      "from": "2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      }]
```

Step2:add a dictionary with value of "from" key  as minimum date of df and "to" should be "from" date the first dictionary in the sorted list. "days" = 0, "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1].

```
{"type": "df_first",
      "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      }
```

Step3:add a dictionary with value of "from" key as 7 days after minimum date of df and "to" should be one days after from

```
{"type": "df_mid",
      "from": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-09T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      }
```

Step4:add a dictionary with value of "from" key  as maximum date of df and "to" should be same as well as "from".

```
{"type": "df_last",
      "from": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      }
```

Step 5: Sort all the dictionary based on "from" date.

Expected Output:

```
[{"type": "df_first",
      "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
     {"type": "quadratic",
      "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
{"type": "linear",
      "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },

     {"type": "polynomial",
      "from": "2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
{"type": "df_mid",
      "from": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-09T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },

{"type": "df_last",
      "from": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      }
]
```

Step 6:

Replace the "to" value of each dictionary with "from" value of next dictionary. "to" value of last dictionary be as it is.

Expected Final output:

```
[{"type": "df_first",
          "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":0,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
         {"type": "quadratic",
          "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
    {"type": "linear",
          "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
    
         {"type": "polynomial",
          "from": "2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
    {"type": "df_mid",
          "from": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":0,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
    
    {"type": "df_last",
          "from": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":0,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          }
    ]
```

Comment: Received your notification, that you tagged me in, i will take a look at this problem..

Comment: @Shubham Sharma Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function `add_dct` that takes arguments as list of dictionaries `lst` with `_type`, `_from` and `_to` and appends a new dictionary to `lst`:

```
dmin, dmax = df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max()
def add_dct(lst, _type, _from, _to):
    lst.append({
        'type': _type,
        'from': _from if isinstance(_from, str) else _from.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT20:%M:%S.000Z"),
        'to': _to if isinstance(_to, str) else _to.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT20:%M:%S.000Z"),
        'days': 0,
        "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
    })
```

Follow this steps as according to your `predefined` requirements:

```
# STEP 1
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda d: pd.Timestamp(d['from']))

# STEP 2
add_dct(lst, 'df_first', dmin, lst[0]['from'])

# STEP 3
add_dct(lst, 'df_mid', dmin + pd.Timedelta(days=7), dmin + pd.Timedelta(days=8))

# STEP 4
add_dct(lst, 'df_last', dmax, dmax)

# STEP 5
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda d: pd.Timestamp(d['from']))
```

Result:

```
[{'type': 'df_first',
  'from': '2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 0,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'quadratic',
  'from': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'linear',
  'from': '2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'polynomial',
  'from': '2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'df_mid',
  'from': '2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-09T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 0,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'df_last',
  'from': '2020-03-14T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-03-14T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 0,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. you are genius. May god bless you

Comment: Finally I would like to replace the "to" value as "from" value of next dictionary. Could you please help me on that.

Comment: can you explain in little more details?

Comment: added the step6, and expected output, just replaced "to" as "from" of next dictionary

Comment: @Danish Can you create a new well formed question, step 6 seems like an step which can be formulated in entirely other question? Just give the sample dictionary in the question and ask about how to replace to with from?

Comment: Also in the expected output `df_mid` `to` value seems wrong? And what about the `to` value in last dictionary, how we replace it?

Comment: edited the expected output. Let "to" value of last dictionary be as it is.

Comment: @Danish Please post a new question, here all this will become pretty jumbled.

Comment: Sure. Created new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955300/change-the-value-of-a-particular-key-each-dictionary-in-a-list-python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218036/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-danish).

Comment: created new question pls help me solve during your free time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236080/replace-the-column-values-based-on-the-list-of-dictionary-and-specific-date-cond