# Change the value of a particular key each dictionary in a list - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as shown below.

```
[{"type": "df_first",
      "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":0,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
 {"type": "quadratic",
  "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z",
  "days":3,
  "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
{"type": "linear",
      "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      },
{"type": "polynomial",
 "from": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
 "to": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
 "days":3,
 "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
      }
]
```

From the above dictionary I would like to replace "to" value of each dictionary as the "from" value of the next dictionary.

The "to" value of last dictionary be as it is

Expected Output:

```
[{"type": "df_first",
          "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":0,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
     {"type": "quadratic",
      "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
      "days":3,
      "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
    {"type": "linear",
          "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          },
    {"type": "polynomial",
     "from": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
     "to": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
     "days":3,
     "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
          }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new dataframe from `records` (list of dictionaries), then use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) on `from` column + [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `to`column and assign it back to `to` column, next use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to get list of dictionaries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df['to'] = df['from'].shift(-1).fillna(df['to'])
records = df.to_dict('r')
```

Result:

```
# print(records)

[{'type': 'df_first',
  'from': '2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 0,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'quadratic',
  'from': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'linear',
  'from': '2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'polynomial',
  'from': '2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}]
```

Comment: created a new question pls look into that during your free time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959037/create-a-new-column-by-looping-over-list-of-dictionary-and-based-on-specific-dat