# create a new column by looping over list of dictionary and based on specific date condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a df and list of dictionary as shown below.

df:

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-02             23              
2020-02-03             14           
2020-02-04             23
2020-02-05             23  
2020-02-06             23          
2020-02-07             30            
2020-02-08             29            
2020-02-09             100
2020-02-10             38
2020-02-11             38               
2020-02-12             38                    
2020-02-13             70           
2020-02-14             70
```

param_list:

```
param_obj_list = [{'type': 'df_first',
  'from': '2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 0,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'quadratic',
  'from': '2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-06T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'linear',
  'from': '2020-02-06T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]},
 {'type': 'polynomial',
  'from': '2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z',
  'to': '2020-02-14T20:00:00.000Z',
  'days': 3,
  'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}]
```

from the above I would like to create a new column into df based on the "type" and date column specified by the dictionary.

I started below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as DT


def time_objective(df, param_obj_list)
    for params_obj in param_obj_list:
        # Do the data processing
        start_date, end_date, label, coef, n_days = params_obj['from'], params_obj['to'], params_obj['type'], params_obj['coef'], params_obj['days']
        print(start_date, end_date, label, coef, n_days)                                           

        start_date = DT.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
        print(start_date)
        if (start_date == 0) | (end_date == 0):
            return df
        elif:
            if len(coef) == 6:
                # Coefficients Index Initializations
                a0 = coef[0]
                a1 = coef[1]
                a2 = coef[2]
                a3 = coef[3]
                a4 = coef[4]
                a5 = coef[5]
                if label == 'df_first':
                    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                    m = df['Date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
                    df.loc[m, 't_factor'] =
```

Explanation:

```
if "type" == df_first:
    df['new_col'] = df['t_factor'] (duration only from the "from" and "to" date specified in that dictionary)

elif "type" == "quadratic":
     df['new_col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + a2*(T)**2 + previous value of df['new_col']
     where T = 1 for one day after the "from" date of that dictionary and T counted in days based Date value

elif "type" == "linear":
     df['new_col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + previous value of df['new_col']
     where T = 1 for one day after the "from" date of that dictionary.

elif "type" == "polynomial":
     df['new_col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + a2*(T)**2  + a3*(T)**3  + a4*(T)**4  + a5*(T)**5 + previous value of df['new_col']
     where T = 1 for start_date of that dictionary.
```

Expected output:

```
Date                t_factor      new_col  
2020-02-01             5          5      
2020-02-02             23         23      
2020-02-03             14         14  
2020-02-04             23         14 + 0.1 + 0.1*(1) + 0.1*(1)**2
2020-02-05             23         14 + 0.1 + 0.1*(2) + 0.1*(2)**2
2020-02-06             23         14 + 0.1 + 0.1*(3) + 0.1*(3)**2 = 15.3     
2020-02-07             30         15.3 + 0.1 + 0.1*(1)    
2020-02-08             29         15.3 + 0.1 + 0.1*(2)   
2020-02-09             100        15.3 + 0.1 + 0.1*(3)
2020-02-10             38         15.3 + 0.1 + 0.1*(4) = 15.8
2020-02-11             38         15.8 +0.1+0.1*(1)+0.1*(1)**2+0.1*(1)**3+0.1*(1)**4+0.1*(1)**5     
2020-02-12             38         15.8 +0.1+0.1*(2)+0.1*(2)**2+0.1*(2)**3+0.1*(2)**4+0.1*(2)**5             
2020-02-13             70         15.8 +0.1+0.1*(3)+0.1*(3)**2+0.1*(3)**3+0.1*(3)**4+0.1*(3)**5      
2020-02-14             70         15.8 +0.1+0.1*(4)+0.1*(4)**2+0.1*(4)**3+0.1*(4)**4+0.1*(4)**5
```

Comment: Hi Danish, have you considered using [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)?

Comment: @rpanai yes I tried but could not implement

Comment: @Danish Can you explain what is `T`?

Comment: @Danish Also how you are assigning values to `new_col`, i mean for example consider dictionary with `type='linear'`  so do we have to assign values in `new column` of dataframe where the date is only  between the start and end date of dictionary?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma T is the time in days, which is one when when ''Date" is one day after "from" date  of the corresponding dictionary

Comment: @Shubham Sharma exactly.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma edited the question little based on your above suggestions.

Comment: @Danish In your dataframe there is no information regarding `timings` eg `HH:MM:SS` but your dictionary does contain, so how do we compare the timestamps, should we compare only the date parts of the timestamps?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes, we compare only date parts of the timestamps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218077/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-danish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function `time_objective` which takes arguments as `dataframe` and `param_obj_list` and returns the dataframe with new column added. Here we have used `Series.between` to create a `boolean mask` and using `boolean indexing` with this mask, fill the values according to the requirements:

```
def time_objective(df, param_obj_list):
    df['new_col'] = np.nan
    for d in param_obj_list:
        if 'from' not in d or 'to' not in d \
             or d['from'] == 0 or d['to'] == 0:
            continue

        if len(d['coef']) != 6:
            print('Exception: Coefficients index do not match')
            return df

        a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = d['coef']

        start = pd.Timestamp(d['from']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        end = pd.Timestamp(d['to']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        T = df['Date'].sub(pd.Timestamp(start)).dt.days
        mask = df['Date'].between(start, end, inclusive=True)

        if d['type'] == 'df_first':
            df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = df['t_factor']
        elif d['type'] == 'quadratic':
            df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = a0 + a1 * T + a2 * (T)**2 + df['new_col'].ffill()
        elif d['type'] == 'linear':
            df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = a0 + a1 * T + df['new_col'].ffill()
        elif d['type'] == 'polynomial':
            df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + a2*(T)**2 + a3 * \
                (T)**3 + a4*(T)**4 + a5*(T)**5 + df['new_col'].ffill()
    return df
```

Result:

```
         Date  t_factor  new_col
0  2020-02-01         5      5.0
1  2020-02-02        23     23.0
2  2020-02-03        14     14.1
3  2020-02-04        23     14.3
4  2020-02-05        23     14.7
5  2020-02-06        23     15.4
6  2020-02-07        30     15.5
7  2020-02-08        29     15.6
8  2020-02-09       100     15.7
9  2020-02-10        38     15.9
10 2020-02-11        38     16.4
11 2020-02-12        38     22.1
12 2020-02-13        70     52.2
13 2020-02-14        70    152.3
```

Comment: if "from"  date or "to" date is 0 or missing in the dictionary raise an exception. also length of coef is not 6 then also raise an exception.

Comment: What kind of exception do you want to raise? I suppose you want `AssertionError`, Right?

Comment: Sharmaif len(coef) == 6:
                # Coefficients Index Initializations
                a0 = coef[0]
                a1 = coef[1]
                a2 = coef[2]
                a3 = coef[3]
                a4 = coef[4]
                a5 = coef[5]
                if label == 'df_first':
                    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                    m = df['Date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
                    df.loc[m, 't_factor'] =  else:
                            raise Exception('Coefficients index do not match

Comment: like in my tried code if len(coef) == 6 execute the code otherwise print exception and retur df as it is.

Comment: @Similarly if the "from" or "to" are missing in the dictionary return df as it is for that time period.

Comment: Pls look into this question during your free time. Similar to above question slight modification.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982000/replace-the-column-values-based-on-the-list-dictionary-and-specific-date-conditi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218159/discussion-between-danish-and-shubham-sharma).

Comment: Created an interesting question. I am learning interpolation got a doubt. Pls look into that during your free time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997758/interpolate-a-pandas-data-frame-in-between-a-particular-date-range-pandas

Comment: Created new question, pls help me to solve this during your free time.

Comment: added similar question, pls look into it during your free time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560565/loop-over-the-given-dictionary-of-list-and-augment-the-given-input-dataframe-bas