# Replace the column values based on the list of dictionary and specific date condition - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two dfs and list of dictionary as shown below.

df:

```
Date                  Tea_Good        Tea_bad     coffee_good       coffee_bad
2020-02-01             3              1           10                7
2020-02-02             3              1           10                7
2020-02-03             3              1           10                7
2020-02-04             3              1           10                7
2020-02-05             6              1           10                7
2020-02-06             6              2           10                11
2020-02-07             6              2           5                 11
2020-02-08             6              2           5                 11
2020-02-09             9              2           5                 11
2020-02-10             9              2           4                 11
2020-02-11             9              2           4                 11   
2020-02-12             9              2           4                 11         
2020-02-13             9              2           4                 11 
2020-02-14             9              2           4                 11
```

df2

```
ObservationDate        beta     
2020-02-01             100             
2020-02-02             230              
2020-02-03             150           
2020-02-04             100
2020-02-05             200  
2020-02-06             180          
2020-02-07             190            
2020-02-08             290 

rf = {
"tea": 
    [
      {
          "type": "replace_beta",
          "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
          "case":"bad"
      },
      {
          "type": "polynomial",
          "from": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
          "case":"good"
      },
      {
          "type": "linear",
          "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":3,
          "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
          "case":"bad"
      },
      {
          "type": "replace_beta",
          "from": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z",
          "to": "2020-02-05T20:00:00.000Z",
          "days":2,
          "coef":[10,10,10,10,10,10],
          "case":"good"
      }],
  "coffee": [
          {
              "type": "replace_beta",
              "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
              "to": "2020-02-10T20:00:00.000Z",
              "days": 10,
              "coef": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
              "case":"good"
          },
          {
              "type": "replace_beta",
              "from": "2020-02-11T20:00:00.000Z",
              "to": "2020-02-15T20:00:00.000Z",
              "days": 5,
              "coef": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
              "case":"bad"
          },
          {
              "type": "replace_beta",
              "from": "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z",
              "to": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
              "days": 3,
              "coef": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
              "case":"good"
          },
          {
              "type": "replace_beta",
              "from": "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z",
              "to": "2020-02-06T20:00:00.000Z",
              "days": 4,
              "coef": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
              "case":"bad"
          }
  ]
        }
```

I tried below code:

```
def sc_user_input(df, df2, sc):


    REQUIRED_KEYS = ["tea", "coffee"]

    for teacoffee_category in REQUIRED_KEYS:
        print(teacoffee_category)
        if teacoffee_category in sc.keys():
            param_obj_list = sc[teacoffee_category]
            
            for params_obj in param_obj_list:
                
                goodbad_catgeory = params_obj['case']
                kind = teacoffee_category + '_' + goodbad_catgeory
                # Do the data processing
                start_date, end_date, label, coef, n_days = params_obj['from'], params_obj['to'], params_obj['type'], \
                                                                params_obj['coef'], params_obj['days']

                #start_date = DT.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                #print(start_date)
                #start = pd.Timestamp(d['from']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                start_date = DT.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                print(start_date)
                #end_date = pd.Timestamp(params_obj['to']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

                # Additional n_days code - Start
                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                df['days'] = (df['Date'] - df.at[0, 'Date']).dt.days + 1
                first_date = df['Date'].min()
                period_days = (start_date - first_date).days
                print(period_days)
                # Additional n_days code - End

                if (n_days != 0) & (start_date != 0):
                    end_date = start_date + DT.timedelta(days=n_days)
                    print(end_date)
                    start_date = pd.Timestamp(start_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    print(start_date)
                    end_date = pd.Timestamp(end_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    print(end_date)
                    


                    if (start_date == 0) | (end_date == 0):
                        return df

                    if len(coef) == 6:
                        # Coefficients Index Initializations
                        a0 = coef[0]
                        a1 = coef[1]
                        a2 = coef[2]
                        a3 = coef[3]
                        a4 = coef[4]
                        a5 = coef[5]

                            # Constant
                        if label == 'constant':
                            if kind == 'tea_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_Good'] = a0 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days)
                            elif kind == 'tea_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_bad'] = a0 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_good'] = a0 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_bad'] = a0 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days)

                        # Linear
                        if label == 'linear':
                            if kind == 'tea_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_Good'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days))
                            elif kind == 'tea_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_bad'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days))
                            elif kind == 'coffee_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_good'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days))
                            elif kind == 'coffee_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_bad'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days))

                        # Quadratic
                        if label == 'quadratic':
                            if kind == 'tea_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_Good'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 2)
                            elif kind == 'tea_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_bad'] = a0 + (
                                                a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 2)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_good'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 2)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_bad'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 2)

                        # Polynomial
                        if label == 'polynomial':
                            if kind == 'tea_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_Good'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 2) + (a3 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 3) + (a4 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 4) + (a5 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 5)
                            elif kind == 'tea_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_bad'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 2) + (a3 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 3) + (a4 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 4) + (a5 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 5)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_good'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 2) + (a3 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 3) + (a4 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 4) + (a5 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 5)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_bad'] = a0 + (
                                            a1 * ((df['days']) - period_days)) + (a2 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 2) + (a3 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 3) + (a4 * (
                                            (df['days']) - period_days) ** 4) + (a5 * ((df['days']) - period_days) ** 5)

                            # Exponential
                        if label == 'exponential':
                            if kind == 'tea_good':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_Good'] = np.exp(
                                    a0)
                            elif kind == 'tea_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'Tea_bad'] = np.exp(
                                    a0)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_good':
                                df.loc[(df['Date'] >= start_date) & (
                                            df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_good'] = np.exp(a0)
                            elif kind == 'coffee_bad':
                                df.loc[
                                    (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date), 'coffee_bad'] = np.exp(
                                    a0)
                                
                        #google mobility
                        if label == 'google_mobility':
                            print(label)
                            if kind == 'tea_good':
                                #df1 = df1[['Date', 'Blue-collar best']].copy()
                                df2 = df2[['ObservationDate', 'beta']]
                                df2.rename({'ObservationDate':'Date'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
                                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                                df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
                                if df2['Date'].max() < pd.Timestamp(end_date):
                                    print(f"we dont have data beyond {df2['Date'].max()}")

                                df =  df.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
                                m = df['Date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
                                df.loc[m, 'Tea_Good'] = df['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['beta']).fillna(df['Tea_Good'])
                                #df.loc[m, 'Blue-collar best'] = df.pop('beta').fillna(df['Blue-collar best'])
                                #df = df1
                                              
                            elif kind == 'tea_bad':
                                #df1 = df1[['Date', 'Int blue-collar']].copy()
                                df2 = df2[['ObservationDate', 'beta']]
                                df2.rename({'ObservationDate':'Date'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
                                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                                df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
                                if df2['Date'].max() < pd.Timestamp(end_date):
                                    print(f"we dont have data beyond {df2['Date'].max()}")

                                df =  df.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
                                m = df['Date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
                                df.loc[m, 'Tea_bad'] = df['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['beta']).fillna(df['Tea_bad'])
                                #df.loc[m, 'Int blue-collar'] = df.pop('beta').fillna(df['Int blue-collar'])
                                #df = df1
                                              
                            elif kind == 'coffee_good':
                                #df1 = df1[['Date', 'White-collar best']].copy()
                                df2 = df2[['ObservationDate', 'beta']]
                                df2.rename({'ObservationDate':'Date'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
                                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                                df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
                                if df2['Date'].max() < pd.Timestamp(end_date):
                                    print(f"we dont have data beyond {df2['Date'].max()}")

                                df =  df.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
                                m = df['Date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
                                #df1.loc[m, 't_factor'] = df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['beta']).fillna(df1['t_factor'])
                                df.loc[m, 'coffee_good'] = df['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['beta']).fillna(df['coffee_good'])
                                #df.loc[m, 'White-collar best'] = df.pop('beta').fillna(df['White-collar best'])
                                #df = df1
                                              
                            elif kind == 'coffee_bad':
                                #df1 = df1[['Date', 'Int white-collar']].copy()
                                df2 = df2[['ObservationDate', 'beta']]
                                df2.rename({'ObservationDate':'Date'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
                                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                                df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
                                if df2['Date'].max() < pd.Timestamp(end_date):
                                    print(f"we dont have data beyond {df2['Date'].max()}")

                                df =  df.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
                                m = df['Date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
                                df.loc[m, 'coffee_bad'] = df['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['beta']).fillna(df['coffee_bad'])
                                #df.loc[m, 'Int white-collar'] = df.pop('beta').fillna(df['Int white-collar'])
                                #df = df1



                        #                     return df
                    else:
                        raise Exception('Coefficients index do not match. All values of coefficients should be passed')
                else:
                    raise Exception('Start date not defined')
        else:
            return df
    return df
```

I am facing below error. I could not resolve

```
"['ObservationDate'] not in index"
```

here is full error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-58a804a79c5c> in <module>
----> 1 sc_user_input(df, df2, scrf).head()

<ipython-input-110-66cf8cded7aa> in sc_user_input(df, df2, sc)
    165                             print(label)
    166                             if kind == 'tea_good':
--> 167                                 df2 = df2[['ObservationDate', 'beta']]
    168                                 df2.rename({'ObservationDate':'Date'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
    169                                 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2804             if is_iterator(key):
   2805                 key = list(key)
-> 2806             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2807 
   2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1551 
   1552         self._validate_read_indexer(
-> 1553             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1554         )
   1555         return keyarr, indexer

~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1644             if not (self.name == "loc" and not raise_missing):
   1645                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1646                 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
   1647 
   1648             # we skip the warning on Categorical/Interval

KeyError: "['ObservationDate'] not in index"
```

Explanation:

```
if "type" == replace_beta:
    df1['col'] = df2['beta'] (duration only from the "from" and "to" date specified in that dictionary)

elif "type" == "quadratic":
     df['col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + a2*(T)**2 + previous value of df['col']
     where T = 1 for one day after the "from" date of that dictionary and T counted in days based Date value

elif "type" == "linear":
     df['col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + previous value of df['col']
     where T = 1 for one day after the "from" date of that dictionary.

elif "type" == "polynomial":
     df['col'] = a0 + a1*(T) + a2*(T)**2  + a3*(T)**3  + a4*(T)**4  + a5*(T)**5 + previous value of df['col']
     where T = 1 for start_date of that dictionary.
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, and besides missing `import datetime as DT`, it works for me (or at least I get a result at the end) so not sure how to help

Comment: @Ben.T is it? for me it is showing error as shown below errors


KeyError: "['ObservationDate'] not in index"

Comment: @Ben.T canyou pls share your out put and input data

Comment: For the input, I used `pd.read_clipboard()` after copying the data you give, I'm pretty sure if you do it as well you'll get the same answer. Then a common mistake in this case would be there are whitespace in the column names? can you check with `print (df2.columns)` if you see any whitespace at beginning or end

Comment: @Ben.T This is the column name
Index(['ObservationDate', 'beta'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Ben.T how pd.read_clipboard() works, can you please share your code

Comment: for the read_clipboard, you just need to select all the data for df1 from your question, copy and then use `df1 = pd.read_clipboard()`, same thing after for df2. I'll see if I can edit your question with the data otherwise

Comment: @Danish Just checked you code and it works..I'm not getting any error.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma But still I am getting the same error

Comment: @Danish Hmm.. that seems strange.. Lets continue discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218159/discussion-between-danish-and-shubham-sharma)